# make azure website only available to other azure websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure

I currently have deployed a WCF service along with 3 different asp.net mvc applications that consume the WCF service, all of the applications have been deployed to a different azure web site. As the WCF application has direct access to the databases of my system **I would like to make it so only the other websites with the asp.net mvc applications have access to it, is this possible?** I tried with ip white listing but I haven't found the websites local ips in order to add the rules and adding the urls of the websites along with enabling DNS reverse lookup does not work either.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A quick way to see what their IP's would be might be to make a request to your WCF layer and inspect the IP there.

Comment: Thanks for your response, wouldn't there be risk of this ip changing without me being notified?

Comment: Probably right. Thomas's answer would probably work best if you want to continue using Azure Websites. Otherwise, you might have to move off PaaS Web Sites and into the IaaS offerings, where I believe you have more control over the networking layer.

Comment: PaaS cloud services would also support this scenario any number of ways. Classic cert auth, e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wouldn't there be risk of this ip changing without me being notified?

Start from last year, you can get static IP Address in Azure.

[How to get a static IP address for your Microsoft Azure Web Site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/05/05/how-to-get-a-static-ip-address-for-your-microsoft-azure-web-site.aspx).

In addition to restricting by IP address, you might also want one more layer of security such as including a token *via HTTPS*.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on a certain hosting environment (which may be subject to future changes), you'll better use an approach with a hard-coded access key, which, in your scenario, can be as simple as handing over a well-known GUID to the service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Thomas. I have never worked with GUID in the .NET framework, I suspect this would involve a change in my code, would the impact be considerable? Also, could you please give me a heads up on where to start making this change? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just create a new GUID with the generator in VS, then, from the client(s), hand it over to the WCF service as an additional URL parameter. On the server side then, check for this exact GUID. That's it - it's only a very small code change.